# Our application loads GUI only if Charles proxy is up and running

Tags: networking, macos, proxy, https, http-proxy

I don't know how to tackle this. My colleague has a desktop app that runs on El Capitan. The app does this:

1. Conects to https://internalserver/Register/register.aspx
2. Once connected it loads some GUI etc etc

This app on this particular Mac sends the petition to the server and it is never delivered - there is just a spinning wheel. In the logs I can see only: `Sending task to the server...`

I read that I could use Charles proxy viewer to see more details. So I got it installed and then run the app and magic is here. The petition is completed and the app works perfectly fine.

I dont understand why this apps works fine only when Charles is up and running. I can use Safari and Firefox for browsing and our internal pages that point to the same https://internalserver/Register/register.aspx are working fine.

Not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end it was a new version of Safari 11.0 that seems to be having some issues with intranet web pages. I installed an older image of El Capitan 10.11.5 that comes with Safari 9.1.1 and all back to normal.